# what's happening in this piece of code from documentation?

Tags: python, pandas

A Noob question,

I am going through documentation and found this sample example, 
I could not understand the conditions for `AAA,BBB,CCC` here in snippet

df:

```
    AAA  BBB   CCC
0    4  2000  2000
1    5   555   555
2    6   555   555
3    7   555   555
```

then,

```
df_mask = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [True] * 4,
   ...:                         'BBB': [False] * 4,
   ...:                         'CCC': [True, False] * 2})
   ...: 

In [10]: df.where(df_mask, -1000)
Out[10]: 
   AAA   BBB   CCC
0    4 -1000  2000
1    5 -1000 -1000
2    6 -1000   555
3    7 -1000 -1000
```

May I know a bit of explaination for the above snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

> **cond** : boolean Series/DataFrame, array-like, or callable
>   Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other. If cond is callable, it is computed on the Series/DataFrame and should return boolean Series/DataFrame or array. The callable must not change input Series/DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).
>
> **other** : scalar, Series/DataFrame, or callable
>   Entries where cond is False are replaced with corresponding value from other. If other is callable, it is computed on the Series/DataFrame and should return scalar or Series/DataFrame. The callable must not change input Series/DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).

So it means it replace `False` value of mask by `other`, here `-1000`.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'BBB': [4, 11, 0, 8], 'CCC': [2000, 45, 555, 85]})
print (df)
   AAA  BBB   CCC
0    4    4  2000
1    5   11    45
2    6    0   555
3    7    8    85

df_mask = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [True] * 4,
                        'BBB': [False] * 4,
                        'CCC': [True, False] * 2})

print (df.where(df_mask, -1000))
   AAA   BBB   CCC
0    4 -1000  2000
1    5 -1000 -1000
2    6 -1000   555
3    7 -1000 -1000
```

If no values in `other` there is replacement to `NaN`s:

```
print (df.where(df_mask))
   AAA  BBB     CCC
0    4  NaN  2000.0
1    5  NaN     NaN
2    6  NaN   555.0
3    7  NaN     NaN
```

You can also pass mask with compare values, e.g.:

```
print (df.where(df > 10, -1000))
    AAA   BBB   CCC
0 -1000 -1000  2000
1 -1000    11    45
2 -1000 -1000   555
3 -1000 -1000    85
```

Comment: print (df.where(df > 10, -1000)) here in this line is it '>' or '< '? for the solution provided

Comment: @Codenewbie - it is boolean mask like `df_mask = df > 10`

Comment: so, it is , for all values less than '10' replace with '-1000'? but here is a confusion, what is '>' df > '10' ? I thought replace '-1000 'for all values of df greater than '10'

Comment: @Codenewbie - or better less or equal, because for  `>` is inverted `<=`

Comment: @Codenewbie - `df > 10` means compare all values of DataFrame with `>`  and value `10`

Comment: Yeah, I got it 4>10 is False so replace with -1000......omg!! If True don't replace anything

Comment: @Codenewbie - yes, exactly. Here is similar function [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), it replace `True` values, so more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

do `print(df_mask)`
You will get the dataframe as below

```
    AAA     BBB     CCC
0   True    False   True
1   True    False   False
2   True    False   True
3   True    False   False
```

with `df.where(df_mask, -1000)`, you are replacing `False` values with -1000 with final out put as below

```
   AAA   BBB   CCC
0    4 -1000  2000
1    5 -1000 -1000
2    6 -1000   555
3    7 -1000 -1000
```

Comment: After framing that DataFrame I felt so noob of myself!!.....Thanks mate