# How to fill NA satisfying particular condition using where

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

In the [Dataframe named titanic](http://%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1TOL.png), how to fill *NA* values in column `Cabin` with value `B` which satisfies the condition `Pclass==3`?

Should use `where`? Something like

`titanic['Cabin']=titanic.where(titanic.Pclass==3).fillna('B')`

Other methods are also appreciated.

@jezreal: [image: reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
titanic = pd.DataFrame({'Pclass':[1,3,3] * 2,
                         'Cabin':[np.nan] * 2 + ['s','d','f'] + [np.nan]})
```

You can select rows by condition for replacement missing values:

```
m = titanic.Pclass==3

titanic.loc[m, 'Cabin'] = titanic.loc[m, 'Cabin'].fillna('B')
```

Or you can chain both conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND` and replace `B`:

```
titanic.loc[(titanic.Pclass==3) & (titanic.Cabin.isna()), 'Cabin'] = 'B'
```

Or solution with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) - conditions are inverted with `!=3`, [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
titanic['Cabin'] = titanic['Cabin'].where((titanic.Pclass!=3) | (titanic.Cabin.notna()), 'B')
```

```
print (titanic)
   Pclass Cabin
0       1   NaN
1       3     B
2       3     s
3       1     d
4       3     f
5       3     B
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it fills 'B ' for Pclass!=3 also modifies the Pclass value.(enclosed the image in main question)

Comment: @Bharath - hmmm, added sample data and working perfect for me.

Comment: it works. Thank you. Btw could you please do it using 'where' as i mentioned in the question

Comment: @Bharath - added to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199674/discussion-between-bharath-and-jezrael).

Comment: Its working perfect. But why titanic.Pclass!=3 is used as i want Pclass==3?

Comment: @Bharath - Because where replace values of non matched mask, it means it replace if `False`. So need invert both conditions - because replace for `False`s. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866439/whats-happening-in-this-piece-of-code-from-documentation/57866486#57866486) for better explanation

Comment: Is there any way to write multiple conditions like (if Pclass==3 then 'B' if Pclass==2 then 'X') in this code "titanic['Cabin'] = titanic['Cabin'].where((titanic.Pclass!=3) | (titanic.Cabin.notna()), 'B')" ?

Comment: @Bharath - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659) - `np.where`  or `np.select` is best use here

Comment: yah i'm aware of np.where .But just curious to know the implementation using the pandas method. Hope you could help

Comment: Ya, then use `titanic['Cabin'] = titanic['Cabin'].where((titanic.Pclass!=3) | (titanic.Cabin.notna()), 'B').where((titanic.Pclass!=2) | (titanic.Cabin.notna()), 'X')`